# IEnumerable.GetProperties()

Tags: reflection, c#-2.0, getproperties

I have class Foo, which derived from interface IFoo and IEnumerable

```
public class Foo:IFoo,IEnumerable
{
   public decimal Count {...}
   ///etc...
}
```

How to call GetProperties(), that it's return only public properties of IEnumerable (not IFoo or this class)?

Answer (score 1):

To get the properties of IEnumerable, you don't even need to reference `Foo`:

```
typeof(IEnumerable).GetProperties();
```

Once you have the properties and you're ready to get values using the `PropertyInfo` object, then you can pass it an instance of the `Foo` class to get the values from.

Comment: If I do this:
PropertyInfo[] pi = typeof (IEnumerable).GetProperties();
it's returns 0 elements.
IEnumerable needed to store records in a table and I need to read all columns and records from it.

Comment: @Dublicator - That's because IEnumerable has no properties. It only contains a single method for getting the Enumerator.